# Spawning child process with express end-point

Tags: python, node.js, express, child-process

I am trying run my python programs in my express server using child processes. The method works if it is plain NodeJS, but it is not working on my API end point.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    a = spawn('python', ['test.py']);

router.get('/test',  function(req, res, next) {

a.stdout.on('data', function(data){

    console.log(data.toString());

  });

  a.stdin.write(JSON.stringify("Hello"));
  a.stdin.end();
});
```

The python program just prints hello.

What is the issue here and how do I fix it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing your `test.py` source code, I'm assuming that `test.py` exits after it outputs all of its data. If that is the case, you will need to move your call to `spawn()` *inside* the route handler.

If this route handler gets called often, you may need to look into using some sort of queue/pool to put a cap on how many processes get spawned at any given time. Without that you could exhaust system resources.

Comment: the python file just just has one line within the main: `print("Hello")`

Comment: "Not working" does not tell me much. Are there errors? What happens or does not happen?

Comment: No errors. The browsers keeps on reloading.... In my Node console, I do not get any code(like 500)... Apart from that, nothing...

Comment: Did you add a `res.end()` or similar in your route handler?